# Prevent long press in changing state on D Flip-Flop

Tags: circuit-design, flipflop

I've made a circuit on Logisim that allows me to switch between three LEDs at the push of a button. Essentially allowing me to cycle between OFF, LED1, LED2 and LED3 repeatedly. I'm doing this using four `D Flip-Flops`.

However, I'm getting an issue that if you hold down the button it will keep cycling through all the options. This isn't much of a problem at low clock speeds but at like 64hz it's unusable. I want to use a higher frequency clock so essentially I want it to only switch when the user presses but if he holds down the switch it won't go to the next iteration in the cycle.

I'm a software developer and can barely remember the stuff I learned in college about circuits so please explain me like I'm 5.

[image: P]

**EDIT**

Thank you guys so much for all the help. I ended up trying to make both the version with 4 flip flops and the one with 3. Both are really good solutions and require about the same amount of circuitry.

4 Flops

[image]

3 Flops

[image]

Comment: If you just want to switch between 4 states. Then why do you need a high clock frequency??

Comment: why not just have the (properly debounced) button *be* the clock?

Comment: Well the problem is at like 1-2hz I will probably have to hold the button down for like half second to switch. But if I hold it too long then I will go to the next level and then I have to cycle all the way back around. So it's not really nice UX for the user. It's simple if it just disregarded thee long presses.

Comment: @Hearth what do you mean by that? sorry I'm a noob

Comment: think about this ... how would you do it in software?

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you create a ring counter.
That would be the easiest way to do so.

[image: 4-bit ring counter]

Here is a link to the info: [Electronics Tutorials - Ring Counters](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_6.html)

Comment: I will try this thanks :)

Comment: @AntersBear CLK is your switch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should build a proper state machine. I think you will need 8 states, so 3 flip-flops would be enough. The additional 4 states would be used to detect the press of a button, so you would only change which LED is illuminated when the current state of the button is pressed and the previous state of the button was not pressed.

Comment: Oh cool thank you this makes sense

Comment: Wont a 3 bit ring counter do the trick?

Comment: @ASWINVENU Won't an Arduino do the trick?

Comment: @HarrySvensson Of course. But look at the question. The man want to achieve this using a logic circuit.

Comment: @ASWINVENU My point was that there's many correct solutions, infinite actually. So far yours require 4 flip-flops meanwhile Elliot's seems to use 3 flip-flops.

Comment: @ASWINVENU Your proposed solution is asynchronous, while the question asked for a synchronous design. Your solution requires a method for initializing the flip-flops to a specific state (1000) without explaining how that would be done. Your method requires four flip-flops, mine requires three. And I wouldn't assume that the OP is a man.

Comment: I AM ACTUALLY A BEAR. ROAR